# CORS Security: Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to Origin on Request Header

Tags: node.js, security, cors

I am unsure of the finer points of the security with regards Access-Control-Allow-Origin and cookies etc.

I was trying to produce an API that allowed authentication from any website. As such I needed to set:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` and

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true`

*This is not allowed due to security constraints.*

However what would be the problem with setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to the value of the `Origin` header of the request? Is that a massive security hole?!

e.g. (node)

```
// CORS
app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');

    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(200).end();
    }

    next();
});
```

Comment: It's a security restriction, not organisation-level policy

Comment: It's very similar to the possible duplicate but I want to know the security implications of not doing the config look up and allowing any origin by pinging the request origin back

Comment: Yes, now I understand -- [the CORS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-cors-20140116/#resource-requests) disallows `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true`: *The [allow-origin] string "`*`" cannot be used for a resource that supports credentials.*

Comment: I think you'd get a faster/better response at http://security.stackexchange.com. If you're interested in migration, flag your own question and with a custom flag saying your the post author and you'd like the question to be migrated. Your question is perfectly on topic here, I think, but I suspect it might do better on Security.SE, personally.

Comment: Nice idea, it is a possible workaround for the problem, that we cannot allow multiple pages at once, just *. For example if you want to allow a dev page on localhost as well, you cannot do that with static header settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header combination could be a risk to your site if you accept a "default" session management method for your API. For example, if session is maintained via cookies (common), basic/NTLM/Kerberos auth (it happens), or client-side certificates (very rare).

If you use an `Authentication: Bearer` header or similar, where the browser does not automatically send the session token, then this probably won't be an issue (unless you accept other methods as well, and your legitimate users use these).

> What would be the problem with setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to the value of the Origin header of the request?

That's exactly the same as allowing the origin `*` and requires no extra effort from any would be attacker. However, you will be able to solve this in a similar way. If you had a pre-approved list of domains that you wanted to allow access, you could check the domain from within the sent `Origin` header, and if it matches an allowed one you could then reflect `Origin` inside `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

The security risk with `*` is that it'll allow *any site* to read content that may contain private user data.

As you are allowing any domain to contact your API with credentials (effectively `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`) you are also allowing other domains to possibly hijack data.

For example, while you victim is logged into your API an attacker forges an email to your victim to go and view a funny video on the attacker's domain `www.evil.com`. While the cat video is playing, the attackers domain makes an AJAX request to your API at `www.example.com/Get_User_Profile_Details` and reads the user's details including DOB, home address, phone number and other details. Implied `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`  and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` will allow this data to be retrieved by CORS when it is normally blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

So to guard against this you should only output the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header for approved domains.

> I was trying to produce an API that allowed authentication from any website.

If you do in fact require access from *any* website then you will need to be careful. You could store the `Origin` of the initial authentication request (i.e. the user entering their username and password) against the session ID. On every request you would need to check the `Origin` and see if it matches the `Origin` stored against the server side session. If so you output the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.org` header (assuming `www.example.org` is where the user logged into) and if not you don't output `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` at all.

You may also find [this post interesting](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/44058/8340).

Comment: I understand the problem that this exposes now. Thank you! BTW when I said "authentication from any website" what I meant was any *of my* websites. So a white list of origins is fine; I just wanted to know the finer points of the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in these things ...

I would suggest in principal it's a little than just having "*" as it would take *some effort* for the caller to put in whatever they'd want.

I would suggest if you really want to tie things down (to approved [API?] users) would be to hold the origin in configuration and check each time?

As I say, I'm no expert.

*For the record Greg sits opposite me at work .. I could have chatted to him about my point of view, but I wanted SO points :-)*